# wifi speed very slow in one of my laptop

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, laptop, windows-11

I'm using two different laptop connected with wifi,

1. Lenovo laptop which having Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 Wireless Network Adapter
2. HP laptop which having intel wireless - AC 9560 160MHz.

In lenovo laptop I am getting very slow speed, in HP I will get good speed.
what causes the problem, how to resolve this issue.

Is my Lenovo network not supporting high speed?
[HP laptop configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3l0UA.jpg),[lenovo laptop configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMOlA.jpg)

**Note:** I'm using 50 mbps wifi speed,for HP laptop will get around 40 to 47 mbps, but in Lenovo I will get around 10 to 15 mbps speed.

Comment: While they're theoretically equivalent the real world conditions may give different results. Among many other factors one may have better support for Bluetooth coexistence. Try using 5GHz APs instead as that automatically overcomes the potential problem.

Comment: I stopped using Atheros adapters with Windows XP and now get Lenovo machines with only Intel Wireless.  That works well. Can you get the card changed?  May need a trip to a computer shop.

Comment: @ChanganAuto do u mean should i change my modem band to 5ghz? but my modem supports only 2.4ghz band. qualcom atheros maximum speed will be around 300 to 400 mbps support, but why iam getting 8 to 10 mbps for 50 mbps speed

Comment: some one pls help me to sort out my issue

Comment: i checked this thread, can u help me which config should i change,[link]https://superuser.com/questions/1570449/wrong-maximum-speed-for-802-11n-standard-what-can-i-do?newreg=8d5b8fea417a4c3c9ce3f12ccf7c2d17